# How to parse XML string in Salesforce using Apex?

Tags: xml, salesforce, apex, lwc

```
<Layout xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <excludeButtons>Submit</excludeButtons>
    <layoutSections>
        <customLabel>false</customLabel>
        <detailHeading>false</detailHeading>
        <editHeading>true</editHeading>
        <label>Information</label>
        <layoutColumns>
            <layoutItems>
                <behavior>Readonly</behavior>
                <field>Hyperlink__c</field>
            </layoutItems>
        </layoutColumns>
        <layoutColumns/>
        <style>TwoColumnsTopToBottom</style>
    </layoutSections>
    <layoutSections>
        <customLabel>false</customLabel>
        <detailHeading>false</detailHeading>
        <editHeading>true</editHeading>
        <label>ABC</label>
        <layoutColumns>
            <layoutItems>
                <behavior>Readonly</behavior>
                <field>TOTAL__c</field>
            </layoutItems>
            <layoutItems>
                <behavior>Readonly</behavior>
                <field>SUBTOTAL__c</field>
            </layoutItems>
        </layoutColumns>
        <layoutColumns/>
        <style>TwoColumnsTopToBottom</style>
    </layoutSections>
</Layout>
```

Above code is input as a xml file now I want to convert this code in to given below output.
output:Information - Hyperlink__c
ABC - TOTAL__c, SUBTOTAL__c

```
please any one help me, its important to me. Thanks.
```

Comment: Hi parvathi. What have you tried so far? Do you have any sample code? Where do you want this output displayed? More details would help us give you an accurate solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by assigning the input xml to an XML Dom Document, for example:

```
Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
doc.load(xml);
```

Then, you can access its attributes like this:

```
Dom.XMLNode layout = doc.getRootElement();
Dom.XmlNode[] layoutSections = layout.getChildElements();
```

Once you have access to the layout sections, you can loop through them and access specific child elements with:

`String label = layoutSection.getChildElement('label', null).getText();`

Note that a layoutSection is of type `XmlNode` which means you can keep going through its child elements and access its values.

Answer (score 0):

The following example uses a recursive algorithm to parse the XML stream and convert it to a Map<String, Object> format.

```
public class TestSwapnil {
    
    //method to initiate recursive parsing of XML stream
    public static Map<String, Object> xmlToMap(String xml){
        
        //initialzing XML document
        Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
        doc.load(xml);
        
        //getting the root element and parsing it recursively
        Dom.XMLNode root = doc.getRootElement();
        Object temp = parse(root);
        
        //map to store parsed data
        Map<String, Object> jsonResult = new Map<String, Object>{root.getName() => temp};
        
        //result map having data from the XML string as a map
        return jsonResult;
        
    }
    
    //method to recursively parse child nodes from XML document
    private static Object parse(Dom.XMLNode node){
        
        //map to store data of current XML node
        Map<String, Object> jsonResult = new Map<String, Object>();
        
        //getting list of child elements
        List<Dom.XMLNode> children = node.getChildElements();
        
        //if no child elements found, we simply return the text value
        if(children.isEmpty()){
            return node.getText();
        }

        //map to store occurence count of child elements against their names       
        Map<String, Integer> nodeNameCount = new Map<String, Integer>();
        
        //iterating over child elements and populating the count in map
        for(Dom.XMLNode child : children){
            
            String nodeName = child.getName();
            
            if(!nodeNameCount.containsKey(child.getName())){
                nodeNameCount.put(nodeName, 0);
            }

            Integer oldCount = nodeNameCount.get(nodeName);
            nodeNameCount.put(nodeName, oldCount + 1);
            
        }
        
        //iterating over child elements and parsing them recursively
        for(Dom.XMLNode child : children) {
        
            Object temp = parse(child);
            String nodeName = child.getName();
            
            //checking if this child is an array 
            Boolean childIsArray = (nodeNameCount.get(nodeName) > 1);
            
            //if child is array, save the values as array, else as strings. 
            if(childIsArray) {  
                
                if(jsonResult.get(nodeName) == null){
                    jsonResult.put(nodeName, new List<Object>{ temp });
                }
                else{
                    List<Object> tempList = (List<Object>)jsonResult.get(nodeName);
                    tempList.add(temp);
                    jsonResult.put(nodeName, tempList);
                }
               
            }
            else{
                jsonResult.put(nodeName, temp);
            }
        }
        
        //result map for current node
        return jsonResult;
        
    }

}
```

I have used the following block of code to test the above methods in Anonymous window :

```
//input xml data
String xml = '<book><title>Some title</title><description>some description</description><author><id>1</id><name>some author name</name></author><review>nice book</review><review>this book sucks</review><review>amazing work</review></book>';

//parsing xml data and printing to debug logs
Map<String, Object> jsonResult = TestSwapnil.xmlToMap(xml);
System.debug(jsonResult);
```

Output in Debug logs :

```
22:57:28:007 VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT [15]|jsonResult|

{
  "book": {
    "title": "Some title",
    "description": "some description",
    "author": {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "some author name"
    },
    "review": [
      "nice book",
      "this book sucks",
      "amazing work"
    ]
  }
}

|0x698881dd
```